# How to iterate in Pagination drop down having values 10,25,50,100 in the drop-down using for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr8WA.png)

Another method to iterate and select all the Dropdown values

```
Select dropdown= new Select(WebUIDriver.webDr.findElement(By.xpath("enter xpath")));
int noOfDropDownValues=  dropdown.getOptions().size()-1;

for(int i=0;i<noOfDropDownValues;i++){
    new Select(WebUIDriver.webDr.findElement(By.xpath("Enter Xpath']"))).selectByValue(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the html code its hard to tell if using Select Class will work, as it only works with elements with Select Tag but you can try doing selecting them by index, this will select all options in dropdown one by one

```
        Select dropdown = new Select(WebUIDriver.webDr.findElement(By.xpath("enter xpath")));
        int noOfDropDownValues = dropdown.getOptions().size() ;

        for (int i = 0; i < noOfDropDownValues; i++) {
        dropdown.selectByIndex(i);
        }
```